# Adding Ctrl+Alt+Del requirement and pre-login message in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notifications

I would like to require Ctrl+Alt+Del to login at the beginning of boot up, and I would also like to have a notification come up stating that the system is actively monitored and tracked. How do I do this in Windows 7 Professional 64-bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a blog article showing how to configure that option using the Group Policy Editor :

- http://www.mydigitallife.info/enable-press-ctrlaltdel-secure-logon-on-windows-7-or-vista/

You'll need to use method #2 (Run `secpol.msc`, expand Local Policy -> Security Options), and change the policies:

- Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on (Make this Enabled and enter your desired message)
- Interactive logon: Message title for users attempting to log on (Make this Enabled and enter your desired caption)

in addition to

- Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL (Make this Disabled, instead of Not Defined, in order to *require* CAD)

as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Nice, thanks, but that is only a partial answer to the question.  I would also like to put up a notification, how do I do that?  I assume the same tool, but...

Comment: @LordofTime: Patience, man, you got an answer in under 10 minutes, for free.

Comment: @Oliver: How's that?  Should be enough detail to follow, without lifting any screenshots without permission from the blog.

Comment: Indeed, i needed this quickly, though, because this system needs to go to a supervisor (they got a new system, and this was the last part of the policies i needed to set).  I figured out the second half, though, in the same screen, its "Interactive Logon: Message Title for Users Attempting to Log On", and "Interactive Logon: Message Text for Users Attempting to Log On"