# Disabling listing of users at Windows 7 login screen

Tags: windows-7, login

I'd like to be able to, in addition to setting up CAD and a message at login, to not allow the system to list all users on the system in Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

How do I go about doing this?  Also if a user has their user name as "FirstName LastName", how would they enter that into the login screen after the easy listing of users is disabled?

Related: [Adding Ctrl+Alt+Del requirement and pre-login message in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/441336/adding-ctrlaltdel-requirement-and-pre-login-messsage-in-windows-7)

Comment: I do not believe this to be possible.  This is an underline functionality of Windows since Windows XP.

Comment: But you could disable it in XP.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Group Policy Editor (the same as in the linked question) go to Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Logon and enable the "Always use classic logon" option.  You may need to reboot.

Note that this only works if you've already configured the system to require Ctrl+Alt+Del at logon.

Comment: Actually I lied, it worked until I restarted another time, and it failed.  Any other suggestion?

Comment: It should work; perhaps the setting got reverted somehow?

Comment: Nope, its still showing up, and the policy is enabled.